# handling Fragments on Config Change

Tags: android

My application contains two fragments.

My Android manifest file contains the following line:

`"android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

which I need for the second fragment. I don't want its onCreateView() or other method to be called an orientation change.

But my first fragment needs onCreateView() to be called when orientation changes. Since the manifest file  contains the above line, the onCreateView() method is not called. Can anyone help me in sorting out this to make onCreateView() to be called when orientation changes for specific fragment?

Comment: Then you have to delete that configChanges line from Manifest, and handle orientation change in both Fragments yourself.

Comment: The reason is I have more than  2 fragments ,in that case how to handle this situation

Answer (score 0):

I believe [setRetainInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) is the function you need.

From documentation:

> Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity
> re-creation (such as from a configuration change). This can only be
> used with fragments not in the back stack. If set, the fragment
> lifecycle will be slightly different when an activity is recreated:
>
> - onDestroy() will not be called (but onDetach() still will be, because
>   the fragment is being detached from its current activity).
> - onCreate(Bundle) will not be called since the fragment is not being
>   re-created.
> - onAttach(Activity) and onActivityCreated(Bundle) will
>   still be called.